# Backbone trigger two methods in one event

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am using Backbone and I have a view with events defined:

```
    ....
    events: {
        'click .search-button': 'setModelTerm',
        'change .source-select': 'setModelSourceId',
        'change .source-select': 'activateSource'
    },
    ....
```

I would like to trigger two methods when the event `change .source-select` fires. The problem is that the last entry in the event object overrides the preceding entry.
How can I trigger two methods in one event?
(I am trying to prevent writing another method that calls those two methods)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can pass a wrapper function in your hash of events to call your two methods.

From http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

> Events are written in the format `{"event selector": "callback"}`. The
>   callback may be either the name of a method on the view, or a direct
>   function body.

Try

```
events: {
    'click .search-button': 'setModelTerm',
    'change .source-select': function(e) {
        this.setModelSourceId(e);
        this.activateSource(e);
    }
},
```

Comment: I wrote it specifically! "I am trying to prevent writing another method that calls those two methods".

Comment: @Naor If you want to declare something like `'change .source-select': 'setModelSourceId activateSource'`, you'll have to override view.delegateEvents http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-156 which seems slightly overkill to me

Comment: Is there any way to to give a single function for multiple events?

Comment: @Prasanna You can pass the same target function multiple times, something like `events: {'event1': 'name_of_function', 'event2': 'name_of_function'}` assuming `name_of_function` is defined on the prototype of your view

Comment: thanks but i solved it this way

    events : {'click #btn1,#btn2,': 'function'}

Comment: I don't get why backbone allows multiple events one function and not multiple functions one event...

Answer (score 8):

The only thing that is keeping you from adding the same event/selector pair is that `events` is a hash - jQuery can handle multiple bindings to the same element/event pair. Good news though, jQuery events allow you to namespace events by adding a `.myNamespace` suffix. Practically speaking, this produces the same results but you can generate many different keys.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click.a .foo': 'doSomething',
    'click.b .foo': 'doSomethingElse'
    'click.c .foo': 'doAnotherThing', // you can choose any namespace as they are pretty much transparent.
  },

  doSomething: function() {
    // ...
  },

  doSomethingElse: function() {
    // ...
  },

  doAnotherThing: function() {
    // ...
  },
});
```

Comment: this is life-changing

Comment: the unsung hero here

Answer (score 1):

The events hash in your view is just a convenience "DSL" of sorts. Just bind your 2nd event manually inside `initialize`.

```
events: {
    'click .search-button': 'setModelTerm'
},
initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.on('click .search-button', this.doAnotherThing);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. Using this.on binds to Backbone.Events mixin to the view not the DOM events. If you want to manually add DOM event callbacks, use:
`this.$el.on('click',  '.search-button', this.doAnotherThing);`
which is what the `events` hash does behind the scenes.

Comment: And if you want them to be undelegated with the rest of the events on `undelegateEvents`, add this suffix to the event name: `'click.delegateEvents' + this.cid`

Comment: @KentWillis can you post an answer with the correct code please?

Comment: Found a better way to solve this and posted it as an answer. But if you still want to manually add an event, do: ```this.$el.on('click.delegateEvents' + this.cid, '.search-button', this.doAnotherThing);``` in an override of the ```delegateEvents```. Make sure to call ```Backbone.View.prototype.delegateEvents.call(this);``` at the beginning of the override. This will let the view manage this custom DOM event callback alongside the other events.